# Why am I receiving the error "module 'msw' has no exported member rest" for my import "import { rest } from 'msw'"

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, vitest

I am following the example here:

https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro/

At the "Step-By-Step" section under "Imports" it says this:

```
// import dependencies
import React from 'react'

// import API mocking utilities from Mock Service Worker
import {rest} from 'msw'
import {setupServer} from 'msw/node'
```

At first, I received an error for this line:

```
import {setupServer} from 'msw/node'
```

But I ran the command:

```
npm install msw@latest
```

And that fixed that particular error. However, this error:

`Module '"msw"' has no exported member 'rest'. ts(2305)`

At the line:

```
import { rest } from 'msw'
```

where "rest" is spelled out, still remains.

This is what I am working with:

- node: 18.17.1
- npm: 9.8.1
- typescript: 5.3.3

I appear to have the latest 'msw' as I performed that "`install msw@latest`", but I cannot figure out this error.

Comment: If you use VS code do window reload or restart VS code, this can happen and it is very common. I hope this solves it, otherwise it is really an issue with the library

Comment: @mssp Unfortunately, that did not fix it. Thank you for the suggestion, though.

Comment: One last suggestion I have is delete `node_modules` and do a fresh `npm i`, if you have not done that. Otherwise I can't think of anything else

Comment: @mssp Still nothing ... thanks anyway.

Comment: Why not check the [MSW docs](https://mswjs.io/docs)?

Comment: @Phil Because I am new to React.JS, Next.JS, and Vitest testing, and I was following a tutorial to learn more, and had no idea what "msw" was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newest MSW version has deprecated rest in favor of http.

The solution then should be to update your import to:

import { http } from 'msw';

From there you can follow the migration guides at this link: https://mswjs.io/docs/migrations/1.x-to-2.x/ to ensure you're properly setting up your mocks.

Comment: Thank you for your extremely helpful, yet non-judgmental answer. The Guide you pointed me to has all the answers I need.

Comment: This is absolutely the way to go! Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

try to use " import { http } from 'msw' " instead

https://mswjs.io/docs/migrations/1.x-to-2.x/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).